# Adding a read more link to jQuery Autoellipsis? (Autoellipsis adds the "..." at the end of text with fixed height)

Tags: jquery, ellipsis

I'm using a jQuery Plugin called [Autoellipsis](http://pvdspek.github.com/jquery.autoellipsis/).

It adds the "..." at the end of text with fixed height.

For example:

**With ellipsis and height:**

```
<div style="height 20px;">
```

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam
>   nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat
>   volutpat...

```
</div>
```

**Without ellipsis nor height:**

```
<div>
```

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam
>   nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat
>   volutpat Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed
>   diam dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.

```
</div>
```

To apply the ellipsis you only have to do this
(The ellipsis is applied only if the element has height):

```
  // Apply ellipsis
  $j('.reply-content p').ellipsis();
```

HTML:

```
<div class="reply-content">
<span class="topic-author-link">
<span class="topic-post-date">
<span class="bbp-admin-links">
<p>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</div>
</p>

<!-- etc... -->
```

I would like to add a read more button:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam
>   nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat
>   volutpat euismod tincidunt ut laore tincidunt ut laoreet... **read more**

so the full text appear when you click the read more link right after the ellipsis (e.g. keeping just two lines of text).

Any suggestions to accomplish this?

**EDIT:**

Plugin Options (just in case):

> .ellipsis( [selector], [options] )
>
> Perform ellipsis on jQuery selection. The optional selector defines
>   the sub-elements which will be affected by the ellipsis operation.
>   selector The selector selecting the sub-elements to perform ellipsis
>   on. If no selector is given, the plugin defaults to performing
>   ellipsis on all child elements. options A map of additional options to
>   pass to the method. Supported are:
>
> **ellipsis** The ellipsis character or string to use. Defaults to
>   "..." (three dots).
>
> **setTitle** Sets the title attribute of the affected elements with
>   the original content. May be set to either never, onEllipsis or
>   always. When using onEllipsis, the title attribute will only be set
>   when the content of the element was indeed ellipsed. Defaults to
>   never.
>
> **live** When set to true, perform ellipsis on current and future
>   elements matching the jQuery selection. Also reapplies the ellipsis
>   when the target elements' dimensions change. Use with care, as this
>   mode polls the selection elements. Defaults to false.
>
> The method returns the jQuery object for chaining purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the source of the plug-in, the settings object looks like this:

```
var defaultSettings = {
  ellipsis: '...',
  setTitle: 'never',
  live: false
};
```

So the `ellipsis` option is not actually a character, but (by default) three characters. A quick skim of the code doesn't turn up any obvious spot where the magic number three is used, so there's a good chance you can simply supply a different `ellipsis` option, like

```
ellipsis : ' <a href="something">Read More...</a>';
```

It's certainly possible things may break, but it's a start.

Comment: Thanks but now how can I make the full text appear?
(By the way, I discovered that leaving a space there hangs the browser).

Comment: @alexchenco, there are numerous ways to go. You need some sort of unEllipsis() function triggered by the click. The unabridged text has to be stored somewhere, and the function will either swap it in for the abridged version, or perhaps reveal it while hiding or removing the abridged version.

Comment: @alexchenco if u need a space, u could use "no break space" code String.fromCharCode(160), eg.: ellipsis: String.fromCharCode(160) + '...', which adds white space before ...